# Nested promises and promise.map

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm using promises for a NodeJS project and I don't know how to make it work. I have managed to simplify it to something like this:

```
function getProperties(participant, queries){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    Promise.map(queries, function(query){
      return request.getAsync(query).then(function(response){
        return JSON.parse(response.body)['data'];
      });
    }).then(function(results){
      // process results and create rule
      resolve(rule);
    });
  }

function getParticipants(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // send a request for the list of posible participants
    for (participant in participants_list) {
      // determine which properties we need to query
      requests.push(getProperties(participant, queries))
    }
    Promise.all(requests).then(function(result){
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

getParticipants().then(function(rule){
  // process the rule
});
```

Basically, I have to determine which partipants are allowed to take part in a race and I have to request the list of participants, then queries for their properties and process everything. I'm trying to use promises so that the system waits for the results of a request before making the others. It's my first time using promises, so I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: Are you using Bluebird or some other promise library? `Promise.map` isn't part of the native Promise implementation...

Comment: @Frxstrem - certainly looks like Bluebird, that `.getAsync` looks like a promisified get

Comment: `simplify it to something like this` - well, here it is further simplified - https://jsfiddle.net/4pa1npvk/

Comment: @consr What's your question exactly? Is there an error you are receiving when running this code? Do you just want clarification on the structure of the promises?

Comment: The function `getProperties` ultimately delivers a `rule` so would the function not be better named `getRule`?
Similarly, the function `getParticipants` ultimately delivers an array of `rule`s so would the function not be better named `getRules`?

Comment: @Frxstrem I'm using Bluebird, I forgot to say it.

Comment: @Matt It doesn't give any output and after some time, I receive a socket hangup error, I would like clarification on the structure because I'm not sure of it.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I simplify it for the question, the rules represent the participants and they are updated with the properties, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Code looks like it should be close to working but it's hard to tell from the simplified version. Maybe you could publish a (non-) working demo of the full code. eg as a code snippet.